# Magento Email Template

Tags: email, magento, templates

Hi I am currently working on a custom theme and found out that order emails are not being sent.

Details: 
CE version 1.9
Custom Package.

At first I though it was the cronjob but I don't think it's that since it's sending from the RWD theme.

I removed all custom XML and tried adding them one by one but same problem...

I was wondering if you guys know how can I debug this problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What is your host? 
Only orders e-mails? You have to check if the other mails are OK.
Turn on the logs and see that maybe have an error.

Comment: Nothing in the log, no errors, nothing!!! but I found a solution by creating a file /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php and changed line 407 from if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)  to if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue))

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1/52187#52187) but I wanted to add that instead of modify the core file like suggested in the previous post, I overwrote the file by creating it on my local.

Created a file on:
/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php

and changed line 407 from

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)
```

to

```
if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue))
```